# Another "PATH is not set up!" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal, rubygems

So I've been lurking on here for a solution to my problem. I am trying to run ruby and install gems on my OSX via terminal. I am trying to get my path setup, but I am running into multiple issues here. When i try to run rvm ls I get

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin' is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for 'PATH=...' entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles'.
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.4.0'.
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
```

my bashrc file has

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

and my .bash_profile

```
    [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

also when I try to run rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles, I get this:

```
    Adding rvm loading line to /Users/user/.profile /Users/user/.bash_profile /Users/user/.zlogin.
    Installing rvm gem in 2 gemsetsError running 'command gem install /Users/user/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc',
please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/1515684005_ruby-2.4.0/gem.install.rvm->=1.11.3.9.log
Error running 'command gem install /Users/user/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc',
please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/1515684005_ruby-2.4.1/gem.install.rvm->=1.11.3.9.log
.
    Installing gem-wrappers gem in 2 gemsetsError running 'command gem install /Users/user/.rvm/gem-cache/gem-wrappers-1.3.2.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc',
please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/1515684005_ruby-2.4.0/gem.install.gem-wrappers->=1.3.2.log
Error running 'command gem install /Users/user/.rvm/gem-cache/gem-wrappers-1.3.2.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc',
please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/1515684005_ruby-2.4.1/gem.install.gem-wrappers->=1.3.2.log
.
```

Sorry if this is a very simple and basic solution, I haven't messed around with ruby or terminal/homebrew in a while, so I am lost

Comment: Can you remove this `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` from the `bash_profile` and just leave the one in `.bashrc`

Comment: Warning says rvm's bin should be at first place. So try to change `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"` to `export PATH="$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: I've done both and I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from your .bashrc file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Comment: That didn't work either, I did that, restarted, and it's the same result

Comment: `echo $GEM_HOME` will show where your gems are being installed.  The problem seems to be that rvm is not first in your PATH.